# Strategies for calling grpc service from a webapi in .net Core

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, grpc

I have a rest/web `API` in `.Net` Core that I am using as an aggregation service to call some underlying `gRPC services` also in `.Net core`.  For the `WEB API` client, I am creating the channel once as a singleton on startup and injecting it where I need it using dependency injection.  I am also thinking of creating the clients to the `grpc services` on startup and then injecting them.  Is creating the channel and the clients on Startup the correct strategy or should I create and close the channel and clients on every requests of the `web API`?  Furthermore, if creating the channel once is the correct strategy how do I ensure that the channel is closed on shutdown....Both the `web API/rest` service and the `grpc services` will be running on a `Kubernetes Cluster` as docker containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't create a new channel for every call you make. gRPC channels are supposed to be long-lived and you'll generally get the best performance and resource utilization if you create a channel once and then keep invoking subsequent calls on that channel. The exact scope at which you create the channel depends on your application - but creating the channel only once at application startup is one of the possible approaches (also note that TCP/IP connections are created lazily - a new connection won't be created until you start a first call on that channel).